# Rails ActiveRecord - Cleanup for counting associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

My friend helped me to do some cleanup - but it doesn't look much like rails active record way.

first i wrote this way:

```
@count_users_approved = current_agent.users.map { |u| u.orders.where("created_at >= ? AND order_status_id = ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, "3")}.count
```

# rather counting the records, the result was displaying in this way : [0,0,1]

My friend fixed it by writing it in this way:

```
@count_users_approved = Order.where("created_at >= ? AND user_id IN (?) AND order_status_id = ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day, current_agent.users.map(&:id), 2).count
```

can we write this much cleaner and ActiveRocord type ?

This is how my models are designed.

```
class Agent < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent
  has_many :orders
  has_many :support_histories
  has_one :card_info
end

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :order_type
  belongs_to :order_status
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go this way :

```
@count_users_approved = Order.joins(:user).where("orders.created_at >= ?", DateTime.now.beginning_of_day).where(users: {agent_id: current_agent.id}, order_status_id: 2).count
```

You're joining the user table to test that the user is assigned to the current agent.

Also there's no need to map for ids, you could have just passed the `current_agent.users` array, Rails extracts ids of objects for you when building the query.

Comment: am getting this error :(
Mysql::Error: Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `orders` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` WHERE `users`.`agent_id` = 1 AND `orders`.`order_status_id` = 2 AND (created_at >= '2012-10-23 18:30:00')

Comment: :) Many thanks brother, that worked... I am very new to rails. and today i nearly spent 3 hrs to fix it :) thanks, thanks, thanks...